# Remove tabs from a UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I have a custom UITabBarController and I'm trying to dynamically remove items from it, depending on the user's settings.

Here is the first attempt:

```
-(void) updateTabs {
    NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];
    [tabs removeObjectAtIndex:3];
    [self setViewControllers:tabs animated:YES];
}
```

With this attempt, tab bar also gets messy, with the spacing not updating as expected until you click on the icons a few times.

Here is the second attempt:

```
-(void) updateTabs {

    NSMutableArray *tabs = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];
    [tabs removeObjectAtIndex:3];
    [self.tabBar setItems:tabs animated:YES];
}
```

This attempt, the app terminates, with the error: 'Directly modifying a tab bar managed by a tab bar controller is not allowed.'

I'm not sure if this is relevant or not, but the code is called on a notification received here:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
    selector:@selector(updateTabs) name:@"SettingsUpdated" object:nil];
```

There are a few similar questions on StackOverflow, which tend to point to my two attempts above. Does anybody have any suggestions on the best way to get this working?

Comment: In order to test what's happening, I added a `setBadgeValue` into the updateTabs function. It appears that the view isn't updating right away, which I'm guessing is part of the problem. I added a `[self.view setNeedsDisplay]` too, but that didn't help.